# Importing cad model in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi ,

I want to import cad models in gazebo3 to create the environment. Can anyone suggest how can I do that? Is there any tutorial related to this?I want to import cad model stored as .stl format developed in solidworks tool into gazebo 2.2 version. I used blender to convert it into .dae file. when I import it into gazebo it automatically starts moving without applying any forces or velocity and starts falling down . Then I convert it first to .obj file and then .dae but then also it behaves the same. Can anyone suggest what is wrong?  here I am attaching my .dae file . I saved it as .sdf because it wasn't accepting the .dae format while attaching. The attached file is .obj to .dae converted file. Thanks!
[objTO dae.sdf](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1430132775504428.sdf)

Here is the sdf for above mesh.

```
 <sdf version="1.4">
  
  <model name="robot">
 
   <link name="link1">

      <inertial>

        <mass>10000.0</mass>

        <inertia>

          <ixx>140</ixx>

          <ixy>0.0</ixy>

          <iyy>550</iyy>

          <ixz>0.0</ixz>

          <iyz>0.0</iyz>

          <izz>550</izz>

        </inertia>

      </inertial>

      <visual name="visual">

        <!-- rotate mesh to get to X-forward -->

        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 -1.570796</pose>

        <geometry>

          <mesh>

        <scale>20 20 20</scale>

            <uri>model://robot/meshes/untitled3.dae</uri>

          </mesh>

        </geometry>

      </visual>

      <collision name="collision">

    <geometry>

      <mesh>

            <scale>100 100 100</scale>

        <uri>model://robot/meshes/untitled3.dae</uri>

          </mesh>

        </geometry>

      </collision>

    </link>

  </model> 

  </sdf>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7751/importing-cad-model-in-gazebo/) by [anonymous](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/957/anonymous/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-04-28**:
I was able to load your model. Note that the collisions are positioned and scaled differently from the visuals. At first it was falling through like yours, but then I exported the model path and it now collides with the ground. (cd ; export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=`pwd`:GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH)

**Comment by [anonymous](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/957/anonymous/) on 2015-04-29**:
Yes, the issue was because of different scaling factor of collisions and visuals.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I usually use blender to convert .stl or .ply to .dae  which can be read in sdf file

download link
http://www.blender.org/

---

Originally posted by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) with karma: 80 on 2014-12-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[Here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=import_mesh&cat=build_robot)'s a tutorial on how to import 3D meshes into Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2014-12-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1